# Java send screen capture to printer

Tags: java, printing

I need to capture the screen and print it in Java.

I have the following code snippet to write the jpg..

```
BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
File file = new File(fileName);  
ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, file);
```

I think that writing the image to file may not be necessary but at the moment I    would settle for this if I could figure out how to print it

I have found code at ...
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/HelloWorldPrinter.java

which contains ...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now we perform our rendering */
    g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);
```

but I don't know how to change this to print a file.

I have tried

```
try {
    if (! table.print()) {
        System.err.println("User cancelled printing");
    }
} catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException ee) {
    System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", ee.getMessage());
}
```

but this just prints the table instead of the whole screen.

I'm sure just a small change is required to some of the code above but I've been on it for 2 days now.

Should be simple ...

1. Capture screen
2. Print it.

but I can't figure out why it's taking me so long.

Comment: Why are you making a File when you don't need or want to do this? Why not just get the BufferedImage and print it? I'd start by getting rid of any code used to create a file -- unless there's an unknown reason for your creating one.

Comment: Here is a related post: [printing bufferedimage to a printer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15164765/7274990)

Comment: This reply may be printed above''Why are you making a File when you don't need or want to do this? Why not just get the BufferedImage and print it? I'd start by getting rid of any code used to create a file -- unless there's an unknown reason for your creating one. – Hovercraft Full Of Eels''         My answer is "I don't know how to print the BufferedImage"